# Get the values from the Max date after union

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group, teradata

This query works but I'd like to see if there's a more optimize/shorter way to get the same result.  I'd like to retrieve all the data with the maximum date from the union of 3 tables, TABLE_01, TABLE_02, TABLE_03.  Whichever table has the latest bill_date, I want to retrieve the rows for that bill_date.  It will always have more than one row returned for the same PID and bill_date.

```
SELECT T1.PID, T1.BILL_DATE, T2.COL3, T2.COL4, T2.COL5
FROM
    (
     SELECT T.PID, MAX(T.BILL_DATE)
     FROM 
       ( 
         SELECT DISTINCT PID, BILL_DATE, COL3, COL4, COL5
         FROM TABLE_0501
         GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
         UNION ALL
         SELECT DISTINCT PID, BILL_DATE, COL3, COL4, COL5
         FROM TABLE_0502
         GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
         UNION ALL
         SELECT DISTINCT PID, BILL_DATE, COL3, COL4, COL5
         FROM TABLE_0503
         GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
        ) T
     GROUP BY 1  
    ) T1

INNER JOIN

    ( SELECT DISTINCT PID, BILL_DATE, COL3, COL4, COL5
      FROM TABLE_0501
      GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DISTINCT PID, BILL_DATE, COL3, COL4, COL5
      FROM TABLE_0501
      GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DISTINCT PID, BILL_DATE, COL3, COL4, COL5
      FROM TABLE_0501
      GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
    ) T2

ON T1.PID = T2.PID
AND T1.BILL_DATE = T2.BILL_DATE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a QUALIFY clause comes handy here.

```
SELECT * FROM 
( 
    SELECT PID, BILL_DATE, COL3, COL4, COL5
    FROM TABLE_0501
    GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
    UNION ALL
    SELECT PID, BILL_DATE, COL3, COL4, COL5
    FROM TABLE_0502
    GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
    UNION ALL
    SELECT PID, BILL_DATE, COL3, COL4, COL5
    FROM TABLE_0503
    GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
) T
QUALIFY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PID ORDER BY BILL_DATE DESC) = 1;
```

Within each group of PID, a rank will be assigned to rows starting from BILL_DATE to lowest. `QUALIFY ... = 1` will select the highest ranked BILL_DATE.